# Rotate unity button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate a Unity button. Here is my code but it does not work.

```
if (GUI.Button(
        new Rect(95 * Screen.width / 100 - Screen.height / 8, 
                 4 * Screen.height / 5, 
                 Screen.height / 4, 
                 Screen.height / 4), 
        MoreUp) || this.ForceMoreClick)
{   
    this.transform.rotation.x = 10f;
    this.PlayMenuButtonClick();

    this.MoreAnimatedDir = this.MoreAnimatedDir == AnimatedDirection.UP 
        ? AnimatedDirection.UPREVERT 
        : AnimatedDirection.UP;

    this.moreAnimation.ChangeAnimatedDirection(this.MoreAnimatedDir);
    this.ForceMoreClick = false;
}
```

Do I have to use TweenLean for this?

Comment: To rotate individual elements in Unity's immediate mode GUI you need to manipulate the GUI.matrix (RotateAroundPivot rotates the entire GUI) (http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI-matrix.html. It not well documented, or fun, so hardly anybody does it. If you really want to rotate GUI elements frequently, I'd recommend using a WYSIWYG GUI toolkit, like NGUI or 2D Toolkit. They're a bit expensive, but consider how much your time is worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this little bit of code that will rotate the button on click:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

    public class RotateButton: MonoBehaviour {
        private float rotAngle = 0;
        private Vector2 pivotPoint;
        void OnGUI() {
            pivotPoint = new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2);
            GUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot(rotAngle, pivotPoint);
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 25, Screen.height / 2 - 25, 50, 50), "Rotate"))
                rotAngle += 10; //This is rotating it 10 degrees.

        }
    }
```

Maybe it will help you out.
Source: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot.html

Comment: It just does not set the button rotation. It is working. Just does not rotate